# Subsequential promises in ionic2/angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, rxjs

I know, it is a newbie question:

I created a mobile application reading an information feed from a bluetooth serial device.

Data are retrieved using a promise in this way:

```
myServiceClass.getRemoteValue(valueId).then(reply: number) {
   ...
}
```

I need to read multiple parameters coming from this feed and I have to wait the previous call to finish before requesting the new value.

If I run:

```
let requiredValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, ..., n];
for (let i=0; i<requiredValues.length; i++) {
   myServiceClass.getRemoteValue(valueId).then(reply: number) {
      ...
   }
}
```

In this way request will run in parallel, but I need them to run in **sequence one after the other**. Is there any solution to **subsequentially** chain an array of promises someway?

In other words I need to run the n-th promise only after the previous promise has been resolved.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use a recursive method to achieve that... Please take a look at [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/c043Y3?p=preview) (when running the plunker, please notice that the values are being printed in the console)

I'm just using some fake data, but I guess it's enough to give you the overall idea:

```
  public start(): void {
     this.getSeveralRemoteValues([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);
  }

  private getSeveralRemoteValues(array): Promise<boolean> {
    if(array && array.length) {
      return this.getRemoteValueFromService(array[0]).then(() => {
        array.shift(); // remove the first item of the array
        this.getSeveralRemoteValues(array); // call the same method with the items left
      })
    } else {
      this.logEnd();
    }
  }

  private logEnd(): void {
    alert('All promises are done!');
  }

  private getRemoteValueFromService(value: number):  Promise<boolean> {
    // this simulates the call to the service
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => { 
          console.log(`Promise: ${value}`);
          resolve(true); 
        }, 1000);
    });
  }
```

Comment: I ended up with a very similar approach and using BehaviourSubject instead of promises ath the end.